# Anchor on dynamically created Table

Tags: html, asp.net

```
 <asp:Table ID="tbl_Main" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
     **<a href=""> </a>**
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
 </asp:Table>
```

Pretty basic huh? Im populating this from code behind something like this :

```
        int rowCount = myset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        int cellCount = myset.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
        for (int rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rowCount; rowCtr++)
        {
            // Create new row and add it to the table.
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            tbl_Main.Rows.Add(tRow);
            for (int cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCount; cellCtr++)
            {
                // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                tCell.ID = BuildMyPath(rowCtr.ToString(), cellCtr.ToString());
                tCell.Text = "Row " + rowCtr + ", Cell " + cellCtr;
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            }
        }
```

As you can see Ive added an ID to the tCell that i would like to have íts value within the href of the Cell.

Now I've tried close to all the eval expressions from SO, but none of them worked. 
Basically I would like to do something like :

```
<a href="<%= Eval("tCell.ID")%>"> </a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Design:

```
<div id="anchor" runat="server">

</div>
```

in code Behind You have To set:

```
anchor.InnerHtml="Div Content";   //Same use for <a> tag
```

or whatever you want to set

Comment: I would like to avoid using another div and get to understand the eval usage

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this using `LiteralControl` :

```
tCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("<a href={0}>{1}</a>", myPath, textShown)));
```